# Line chart not populated from the first co-ordinate

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report which contains a horizontal list of text field at detail band and line chart at the summary band. The text fields are under a group with group expression as "date". So, it populates a row of data for each date in a month. Finally it looks like a table ( rows of value).

I want to plot a line graph with the values for each date. So I made a series, named as "Target Flow", and value as "$V{Total}" which is retrieved for each date , and category as $F{date_field} nothing but a list of date of the month, and set the 'Increment on' to "None", and 'Reset on' to "Report". Fortunately, my line graph gets plotted. **But it plots the value from second date (2018-04-02) instead of first date (2018-04-01). So, the value for first date is populated on second date , and value for second date  is shown on third date. Likewise value for twenty ninth date is shown on thirty date. Finally thirty date(end date of the month) value is missed from the line chart.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow ! Posting a picture describing your problem could help understanding ;)

Comment: Also, you can use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help writing your question in a more friendly form :) And don't hesitate to edit it !